# access page history in a UWP frame or use dynamic Bindings?

Tags: c#, binding, uwp, navigation, frame

As I understand the UWP [Frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame) documentation, there is a navigation history that enables the frame to call GoBack() and GoForward() to move to the last or next Page on the stack of saved Pages that the Frame created.

Can I use the BackStack property of Frame for the following scenario:

(1) Program should iterate through the last two pages in the Backstack and collect all TextBox.Text's values the user might or might not have entered, then fill a model class with them.

(2) I think the normal way to do this is using TwoWay-Bindings on the TextBoxes, but since I have to create the TextBox-Pages dynamically (basically they consist of a Stackpanel in which I shovel all the controls recognized by a WebService), I am not sure how to add dynamically Bindings.

Please tell me if (1) is possible and/or provide code samples for (2).

Answer (score 0):

for (2) I found in the meantime a nice example at [data bindings in code](https://learnwpf.com/post/2006/06/12/How-can-I-create-a-data-binding-in-code-using-WPF.aspx) and modified it for two way binding:

```
TextBox nameTextBox = new TextBox();
Binding nameTextBinding = new Binding("Name");
nameTextBinding.Source = person;
nameTextBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;   
nameTextBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

nameTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, nameTextBinding);
```